# How to retain connection property in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS project, i need to retain same connection property. I am not able to find how can i retain it. Help me if anybody knows about this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SSIS? You can use shared connections from about version 2012 I rthink. Otherwise you might need to populate your connection manager from an expression that loads from a common config.

Answer (score 0):

This is a property of the connection manager.  Click on the connection manager and open the properties window to set it.